# Main mesh hides other objects

Tags: mesh

My main mesh hides everything around it. For example, i cant see my character's eye in the eye socket nor the lashes above it . But when i render the meshes they are all there. Also, i cant see the bones in the mesh even when the x-ray is enabled. How can i solve this?
[image]

[image]

Comment: I added them to the question as you say

Answer (score 1):

sounds like the meshes that you are looking for are probably hidden (since you cant view them in the viewport (object mode) but they appear in the renderer).

Check your outliner and get a closer look on the "visibility" button if it is turned on, the camera button (next to it) it is also a toggle responsible for the visibility of an object when the scenes is being rendered.

[image]

Also be ensured that the object is in the desired layer and this layer is visible.

[image]

A last option is that you may have changed the layers and the visibility
 in Render Layers tab. So you may need to take a look over there too.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer but they didn't help. Still i cant see the meshes or armatures on the main mesh. Example: http://prntscr.com/kprkst  (x-ray turned on)

Comment: if you pressAlt+H (on viewport) you still not see them ?

Comment: No i cant. I think its not about hiding as you can see on image 1, there is a mesh for brows but we can only see the edge of it because of character's mesh. Normally that brow mesh is in front of the face.